How to implement python's decorators so that it doesn't execute on recursive calls?
I'm actually trying to implement some decorators in Python to test the performances of my programm, but on recursive fonctions it keeps calling the decorator and produce something unreadable.
Here is one of my decorator, I've already try to implement a list that keeps track of which decorator was already called, but it doesn't seem to work.
import functools
import time

def timer(func):
    """Print the runtime of the decorated function with the function signature and return value"""
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapper_timer(*args, **kwargs):
        args_repr = [repr(a) for a in args]
        kwargs_repr = [f"{k}={repr(v)}" for k, v in kwargs.items()]
        signature = ", ".join(args_repr + kwargs_repr)
        print(f"Calling {func.__name__} with argument(s) ({signature})")
        start_time = time.perf_counter()
        value = func(*args, **kwargs)
        end_time = time.perf_counter()
        run_time = end_time - start_time
        print(f"Finished {func.__name__}() in {run_time:.6f} secs")
        print(f"{func.__name__}() returned {repr(value)}")
        print("##########################################")
        return value
    return wrapper_timer


Instead of trying to invent special cases for your decorator, break the recursive function into two parts: one decorated "wrapper" and an inner recursive function.
